# Asp.Net Core CORS and SSL

Tags: reactjs, http, asp.net-core, https

My situation is my frontend is built with reactjs and my backend built with asp.net core 2.2

-frontend: `https://example.com/sub-directory` -with valid certificate

-backend: `https://198.38.x.x:5001` -windows server without a valid certificate

how can I communicate into my backend if my frontend requiring SSL I always got network error?

Startup.cs

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                builder =>
                {
                    builder
                    .WithOrigins("https://example.gov.ph", "http://example.gov.ph")
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
            });

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
```

config.json my frontend code

```
{
  "apiUrl": "https://198.38.x.x:5001/api",
  "url": "https://198.38.x.x:5001",
  "profilePictureUrl": "https://198.38.x.x:5001/Public/Employees/Photos",
  "selectOptionLimit": 10,
  "fileSizeLimit": 10,
  "pageSize": 20,
  "gridSize": { "col": 4, "row": 3 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> When browsers make cross domain calls using XHR, they request CORS
>   headers to decide whether the target server allows access to the
>   source domain.

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ...
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.WithOrigins("https://example.com/sub-directory")
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
        });

        services.AddMvc();
        // ...

    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        // ...
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: Already included in my code. I think my problem is in SSL Certification

Comment: can you replace WithOrigins with AllowAnyOrigin? for test? and then try again.

Comment: I tried that before same result, and there is bug in 2.1 using AllowAnyOrigin

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to add that in your `Startup` class configuration

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
            builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("https://example.com/sub-directory");
            });
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins); 

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should've mentioned what you've tried. What error do you get?

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://198.38.x.x:5001/api/Users/Login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). and net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Comment: But when I Proceed Unsafe in 198.38.x.x:5001 in my backend using chrome it will work as expected.